# Attempting to inherit variable from parent class "NameError: name 'r' is not defined"

Tags: python-3.x

I can't seem to take the radius 'r' variable from the parent 'Circle' class and use it in the child 'Cylinder' class. Tried multiple different ways and can't seem to find my error!

```
class Circle(Point):

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

class Cylinder(Circle):

    def __init__(self,h):
        Circle.__init__(self,r)
        self.h = h
```

This code results in the following error

```
>>> circle = Circle(5)
>>> cylinder = Cylinder(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#123>", line 1, in <module>
    cylinder = Cylinder(3)
  File "C:/Users/theco/Desktop/OOP Shape.py", line 49, in __init__
    Circle.__init__(self, r)
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: you need to pass r to the child constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some issues.

1. You don't call the constructor of the superclass `Circle` by doing `Circle.__init__(self,r)`, but by doing `super().__init__(r)`, which means that I want to call the constructor of the `super` or `Parent` class
2. You are not passing `r` in the constructor of `Cylinder`, (you just do `__init__(self,h):` but somehow you are passing it to the constructor of `Circle` which is not possible, you need to pass both `r` and `h` to the constructor of `Cylinder` like `__init__(self, r, h):`

So your fixed code would look like

```
class Circle(Point):

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

class Cylinder(Circle):

    #Passing both r and h to Cylinder constructor
    def __init__(self,r, h):
        #Passing r to Circle Constructor
        super().__init__(r)
        self.h = h
```

And then when you call it accordingly, you will see that it works now

```
circle = Circle(5)
print(circle.r)
#5
cylinder = Cylinder(5, 3)
print(cylinder.r)
#5
print(cylinder.h)
#3
```

Also just to humor yourself, try to define `area` and `volume` function in `Circle` and `Cylinder` respectively, and you will see the power of Inheritance

```
import math
class Circle(Point):

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

    #Area of circle is pi*r*r
    def area(self):

       return math.pi * self.r * self.r

class Cylinder(Circle):

    #Passing both r and h to Cylinder constructor
    def __init__(self,r, h):
        #Passing r to Circle Constructor
        super().__init__(r)
        self.h = h

    #Volume of cylinder is pi*r*r*h
    def volume(self):

        return self.area()*self.h
```

Then you can call them as follows:

```
circle = Circle(5)
print(circle.area())
#78.53981633974483
cylinder = Cylinder(5, 3)
print(cylinder.volume())
#235.61944901923448
```

Comment: Hi Devesh! Thank you for the help and extra practice. Much appreciated!

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to help and thanks for the accept :)

Comment: If you truly want to do this properly, change the first two lines of `Cylinder` to `def __init__(self, h, *args, **kwargs):` and `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. This ensures that adding extra parameters to `Circle` will automatically allow `Cylinder` to accept them as well.

Comment: While actually it is a good idea, this adds the extra complexity of extracting the values of `r` and `h` from the `args` or `kwargs`, which is not worth for just 2 parameters! What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `r` to the child constructor, and call the parent constructor using `super` instead of `Circle`

```
class Circle(Point):

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

class Cylinder(Circle):

    def __init__(self, r, h): ## added r here 
        super().__init__(r) # changed Circle to super
        self.h = h
```

you can create instances of the two classes by doing:

```py
r = 10
h = 20

a = Cylinder(r, h)

b = Circle(r)
```